# how to split String based on \r\n

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, split

We are Developing `phonegap` application.We get Data form `CSV` file. It's look like this [image: We getting data like this]

We need Data Split into two strings Like
String1 [image]

String2 [image]

We tried like this but We don't have luck so Please guide me

```
var split = string.split('\r\n');
```

Please help me

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Replace the new line characters with space and then split the string with space

```
string.replace( /\n/g, " " ).split(" ");
```

UPDATE:

```
var string1=string.substring(0,string.indexOf("TOTALAMOUNT"));
var string2=string.substring(string.indexOf("TOTALAMOUNT"),string.length);
```

Or if your string contains \n then:

```
var string1=string.substring(0,string.indexOf("\n"));
var string2=string.substring(string.indexOf("\n"),string.length);


alert(string1);
alert(string
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/13h25soo/1/)

Comment: thanks for reply.We tried as you said var newstirng=string.replace( /\n/g, " " ).split(" ");
     alert(newstirng[0]); it's not come with first String Please guide me

Comment: You can refer the fiddle .. http://jsfiddle.net/13h25soo/ .. and you give me your string then i can be able solve it.. @PavanAlapati

Comment: we have data like this it's not String format 
ITEMS,DESCRIPTION,UMO,QTY,PRICE,lineamount,CUSTOMERID,TODAY DATE,ORDERID,BOOKORDER,FOC
BODYLINE SUPER 20 G*10 DOZ,100MG,CTN,1,1093.55,1093.55,ARU011,2015-4-9,Himansu15:9:59059,ABCARU0119590,0



TOTALAMOUNT,DISCOUNT,NET AMOUNT,VAT,GROSS AMOUNT,BOOKORDER,CUSTOMERID,TODAYDATE
38426.87,1,38042.6,2,38803.45,ABCARU011959,ARU011,2015-4-9

Comment: Updated my answer.. check it i think it will help .. @PavanAlapati

Answer (score 11):

try this:

```
var split = string.split(/\n/);
```

Comment: You don't handle the \r here

Comment: var split = string.split(/\r\n/);